# Why google colab is not displaying properly？

Tags: google-colaboratory

As soon as I get to the page that's it, some of the words are extra large and duplicated together.It interferes with my reading and maneuvering.
How to deal with that?Anyone know how to handle this, thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYISz.png)

I have tried many browsers already.